# Drupal Migration Date format

Tags: 7, entities, datetime, migrations

On the old server in the database my date column has rows in this format: **2014-10-15 13:00:00**

When i do $this->addFieldMapping('field_date_time', 'date');
it imports, but is off by 12 hours.

I've tried various ways to convert it in a prepareRow function but with no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Anyone had this issue, or know the proper date conversion in the prepare row function?

Answer (score 0):

Sorta embarrassing, but adding the solution to my problem, just in case anyone else runs into this. If you configure the date field in the content type. There is a drop down of time zone handling. Ours got set incorrectly somewhere down the line. After fixing that, and rerunning the migration everything worked as intended.